# Enable image previews in Loki file manager

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

I want to be able to enable (or even better enable and disable at will) image previews (thumbnails) in Pantheon Files.

[image]

In dconf Editor in org-gnome-desktop-thumbnailers nothing is desabled.

PCManFM and Thunar both have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` 
At the line # Jpeg thumbnailer, set `Disabled=false` or `Disabled=true` to enable or disable jpeg thumbnails.

To enable for png and other image formats, under the line # PixbufThumbnailer in the same file, set `Disabled=false`.

Comment: What about pngs and other images? The above only works for jpegs.

Comment: It's the PixbufThumbnailer in the same file, but it disables all together pngs and other image formats, except jpgs and camera raw.

Answer (score 0):

If tumbler is enabled then you should get thumbnails when viewing local folders (try pressing refresh if not - if still not then try restarting the tumblerd process using gnome-system-monitor or the commandline).

There is a dconf setting that turns on thumbnailing of remote folders.  If you have a recent version then right clicking on a remote folder background should give you a option to turn this on or off.