# File that handles raw thumbnails in Files

Tags: release-loki, files, mimetype

Where is the file that handles camera raw thumbnails in Files? I want to add a mimetype (image/x-sigma-x3f) and see what other adjustments I can make. (I don't think it's the file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer`.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a hint for you, I have just been reading [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9495/6445) explaining how to enable/disable thumbnails by editing the file etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc

In that file you can see that file types (uri-scheme / mime-type combination) are managed by plugins...