# Preview EXR or HDR images in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files, photos

Is it possible to preview EXR or HDR files in Pantheon Files, thumbnails? It works great with KDE Neon and Dolphin.

Answer (score 1):

I had a somewhat similar question before: [File that handles raw thumbnails in Files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/file-that-handles-raw-thumbnails-in-files?s=2|52.1672), but I didn't get a useful answer.

I was considering a Sigma camera and I wanted the camera raw thumbnails in pantheon-files, but I've changed my mind about the Sigma anyway.

The only editable thumbnails files I could find were `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc` and `/usr/share/thumbnailers/evince.thumbnailer`. You can try those, but they didn't work for me.

Another workaround is installing Nautilus, then create the file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/raw.thumbnailer` and add the `mimetype` for the HDR files in it. I'll give you details about it, if you want.